# .net SqlClient and .NET CORE Web API connection string

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it me or tis there a different way that sqlclient and .net core uses the connection string.

**example old client:**

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=SQLSERV1\\SQLSERV1;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myuser; Password=mypass;";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    ....etc
```

Code works fine, results come back from this sql client query.

**Now in .NET CORE web API :**

**appsettings.json**

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
        "ConnectionString": "Data Source=SQLSERV1\\SQLSERV1;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myuser; Password=mypass;"
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(config =>
        {
            config.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        });
    services.AddDbContext<MW_MereSysContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

when i try to nav to the url in my browser i get:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

So how is it that sqlclient sees the server fine, but .net core cannot? is it the way it process the string i.e the fact its on a domain?

Comment: possible sql services stop???

Comment: you mean the sql services in services?  looks fine.  Im running both a the moment to test.

Comment: sql server configuration manager -> sql server services

Comment: on the server yes its running, hence why the sql client program works as mentioned

Comment: Server=SQLSERV1\\SQLSERV1;Database=mydb;User ID=myuser; Password=mypass;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true

Comment: doesnt support MultipleActiveResult‌​Sets=true

Comment: try without it.

Comment: i did, no change ven when set to trusted

Comment: did you try with Integrated Security=True?

Comment: I used this in my project and it worked.
`Server=servername; initial catalog=db;user id=dbuser;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework`

Comment: I wouldn't think you need to escape the backslash (\\\) in the appsettings.json file.

Comment: if i dont it complains in VS

Comment: Are you sure you have no syxtax errors? Store `Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]` into variable and write to `Console.Write` in `Startup`. Is is printed OK?

Comment: Are those settings are in the main appsettings.json file in the Web API project, rather than your data-access project?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Changing `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;` to `Server=tcp:localhost,1433;` solved my problem for the moment

Comment: Did you ever have any luck figuring this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a syntax problem:

```
Data Source=Server\\Instance
```

If you have a default instance, then, only use:

```
Data Source=Server
```

Comment: Yes remove the two ‘\\’ and only use one ‘\’